# How to extend functionality for JSF primefaces component?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I'm using Primefaces 4.0. 
The datatable has an issue that after a table update the filter values are away. There is a new attribute in Primefaces `p:column` "filterValue". The attribute binds the value of a filter to a  backing bean property. The problem is that the value of this attribute is only used for backing bean propertie getter. The setter method is not called.

I have made a patch for this component. In classes `DataTabe` and `DataTableRenderer`, the setter for the method checks in `param`'s what is the client setting for filter and set the backing bean propertie. The changes is made in `DataTableRender` decode and `FilterFeature` decode methods.

Links to original classes on grepcode:

[DataTable decode](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.primefaces.org/org.primefaces/primefaces/4.0-20130705.184420-2/org/primefaces/component/datatable/DataTableRenderer.java#DataTableRenderer.decode%28javax.faces.context.FacesContext,javax.faces.component.UIComponent%29)

[FilterFeature decode](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.primefaces.org/org.primefaces/primefaces/4.0-20130705.184420-2/org/primefaces/component/datatable/feature/FilterFeature.java#FilterFeature.decode%28javax.faces.context.FacesContext,org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTable%29)

So the question: if you want to call setter for a component in which JSF-Phase or which method is suitable for this. Is decode-Method place where you can call setters ? What is standard approach in this situation ?